# SQL query with pivot tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I'm trying to wrap by brain around how to use pivot tables for a query I need. I have 3 database tables. Showing relevant columns:

```
TableA: Columns = pName
TableB: Columns = GroupName, GroupID
TableC: Columns = pName, GroupID

TableA contains a list of names (John, Joe, Jack, Jane)

TableB contains a list of groups with an ID#. (Soccer|1, Hockey|2, Basketball|3)

TableC contains a list of the names and the group they belong to (John|1, John|3, Joe|2, Jack|1, Jack|2, Jack|3, Jane|3)
```

I need to create a matrix like grid view using a SQL query that would return a list of all the names from TableA (Y-axis) and a list of all the possible groups (X-axis). The cell values would be either true or false if they belong to the group.

Any help would be appreciated. I couldn't quite find an existing answer that helped.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2008 Express

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try it like this

Here I set up a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please try to create this in your next question yourself...

```
DECLARE @Name TABLE (pName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @Name VALUES('John'),('Joe'),('Jack'),('Jane');
DECLARE @Group TABLE(gName VARCHAR(100),gID INT);
INSERT INTO @Group VALUES ('Soccer',1),('Hockey',2),('Basketball',3);
DECLARE @map TABLE(pName VARCHAR(100),gID INT);
INSERT INTO @map VALUES
  ('John',1),('John',3)
 ,('Joe',2)
 ,('Jack',1),('Jack',2),('Jack',3)
 ,('Jane',3);
```

This quer will collect the values and perform `PIVOT`

```
 SELECT p.*
 FROM
 (
     SELECT n.pName
           ,g.gName
           ,'x' AS IsInGroup
     FROM @map AS m
     INNER JOIN @Name AS n ON m.pName=n.pName
     INNER JOIN @Group AS g ON m.gID=g.gID
 ) AS x
 PIVOT
 (
    MAX(IsInGroup) FOR gName IN(Soccer,Hockey,Basketball)
 ) as p
```

This is the result.

```
pName   Soccer  Hockey  Basketball
Jack    x       x       x
Jane    NULL    NULL    x
Joe     NULL    x       NULL
John    x       NULL    x
```

Some hints:

- You might use `1` and `0` instead of `x` as SQL Server does not know a *real boolean*
- You should add a `pID` to your names. Never join tables on real data (unless it is something unique and unchangeable [which means **never** acutally!!!])

### UPDATE dynamic SQL (thx to @djlauk)

If you want a query which deals with any amount of groups you have to to this dynamically. But please be aware, that you loose the chance to use this in *ad-hoc-SQL* like in `VIEW` or `inline TVF`, which is quite a big backdraw...

```
CREATE TABLE #Name(pName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO #Name VALUES('John'),('Joe'),('Jack'),('Jane');
CREATE TABLE #Group(gName VARCHAR(100),gID INT);
INSERT INTO #Group VALUES ('Soccer',1),('Hockey',2),('Basketball',3);
CREATE TABLE #map(pName VARCHAR(100),gID INT);
INSERT INTO #map VALUES
  ('John',1),('John',3)
 ,('Joe',2)
 ,('Jack',1),('Jack',2),('Jack',3)
 ,('Jane',3);

DECLARE @ListOfGroups VARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    STUFF
    (
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(gName) 
        FROM #Group
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1,1,''
    )
);

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)=
(
 'SELECT p.*
 FROM
 (
     SELECT n.pName
           ,g.gName
           ,''x'' AS IsInGroup
     FROM #map AS m
     INNER JOIN #Name AS n ON m.pName=n.pName
     INNER JOIN #Group AS g ON m.gID=g.gID
 ) AS x
 PIVOT
 (
    MAX(IsInGroup) FOR gName IN(' +  @ListOfGroups + ')
 ) as p');

 EXEC(@sql); 
 GO

 DROP TABLE #map;
 DROP TABLE #Group;
 DROP TABLE #Name;
```

Comment: Brilliant answer (also thanks for the MCVE).

Just one thought: I am reading between the lines here, but I get this feeling the OP wants to *add a new row* to table TableB and automatically have a new column in the pivot table  *without changing the SQL query*. That will *not work* (to the best of my knowledge). In order to achieve this one needs to create the SQL query for the pivot table dynamically (i.e. add columns to the part ``FOR gName IN( ... )``).

Comment: Almost there. I was able to get the dynamic SQL query to work in MS SQL Server Management Studio, but one question. Can I use that query as a stored procedure? How?

Comment: @PigsIncorporated yes, Stored Procedure should work... just use your actual table and column names

Comment: My question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it may be laborious to keep the pivot up to date if categories are added. Or maybe I just prefer Excel (if you ignore one major advantage). The following approach could be helpful too, assuming you do have Office 365.

I added the three tables using 3 CREATE TABLE statements and 3 INSERT statements based on the code I saw above. (The solutions make use of temporary tables to insert specific values, but I believe you already have the data in your three tables, called TableA, TableB, TableC).

```
CREATE TABLE TestName (pName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO TestName VALUES('John'),('Joe'),('Jack'),('Jane');
CREATE TABLE TestGroup (gName VARCHAR(100),gID INT);
INSERT INTO TestGroup VALUES ('Soccer',1),('Hockey',2),('Basketball',3);
CREATE TABLE Testmap (pName VARCHAR(100),gID INT);
INSERT INTO Testmap VALUES
  ('John',1),('John',3)
 ,('Joe',2)
 ,('Jack',1),('Jack',2),('Jack',3)
 ,('Jane',3);
```

Then, in MS Excel, I added (there may be a shorter sequence but I'm still exploring) the three tables as queries from database > sql server database. After adding them, I added all three to the Data Model (I can elaborate if you ask).

I then inserted PivotTable from the ribbon, chose External data source, but opened the Tables tab (instead of Connections tab), to find my data model (mine was top of the list) and I clicked Open. At some point Excel prompted me to create relationships between tables and it did a good job of auto generating them for me.

After minor tweaks my PivotTable came out like this (I could also ask Excel to show the data as a PivotChart).
[Pivot showing groups as columns and names as rows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cZ5J.jpg)

The advantage is that you don't have to revisit the PIVOT code in SQL if the list (of groups) changes. As I think someone else mentioned, consider using ids for pName as well, or another way to ensure that you are not stuck the next day if you have two persons named John or Jack.

In Excel you can choose when to refresh the data (or the pivot) and, after refresh, any additional categories will be added and counted.